# Ubuntu 18.04.4 How to configure scanner for Epson-4760 wired to network

Tags: networking, drivers, usb, printing, scanner

Printer/scanner is found by all machines and will print from all. But will not scan from box 1 either usb or network. Will scan from remote networked box 2 w/ simplescan or xsane. Ideas to config box 1 either USB or network

```
lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04d9:1702 Holtek Semiconductor, Inc. Keyboard LKS02
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 413c:301a Dell Computer Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

```
scanimage -L
device `imagescan:esci:networkscan://192.168.88.104:1865' is a Epson Et-4760
```

```
# /etc/imagescan/imagescan.conf -- Image Scan configuration
# Refer to the documentation for details on the configuration options
# for the software.  Plugins should come with their own documentation
# if they have configuration options.
#
# Lines starting with a # or a ; are comments.  Comments must be on a
# line of their own.  End-of-line comments are not supported.
[devices]
 net.udi = esci:networkscan://192.168.88.104:1865
 net.vendor = Epson
 net.model = Et-4760
```

Comment: Thanks fpr asking. "Box" means a networked computer, or in the case of "Box 1" a computer connected both via wired network through a Mikrotik router, and a direct USB connection to the printer/scanner.

Comment: Very sorry for omissions. Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS bionic on both devices.  I am really puzzled by the difference in capabilities. One differnce is the status of saned servicxe. On box 2 (network only) I get: $ sudo service saned status
● saned.service - Scanner Service  
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/saned.service; indirect; vendor preset: enabled   Active: inactive (dead)     On Box 1 I get: saned.service-LSB:SANE network scanner server    Loaded (inet.d/saned;generated)    Active: active (exited) ...               so it appears that the service is loaded by two different processes

Answer (score 0):

The scanner problem appears to have resulted from one computer set up with sysV with symlinks and the other with systemd. I made some adjustments to allow systemd to control scannner on both and now both imagescan and Xsane work nicely on either. SysV script is still sitting there on each, but since they both work, I will not make further changes. Printing is fine too, though it appears to be networked only, not USB. BTW, I noticed my version of Ubuntu was included in the OP title. But thanks for your interest.